# Cypher query to exclude results based upon relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I'm trying to out how to exclude nodes from a query. My graph consists of users, skills, skill scoring, questions and endo

- user has skills
- skill has scorings in relation with questions ((skill)-->(scorings)-->(questions))
- endo is a relationship for users and skills scorings ((user)-->(endos)-->(scorings))

I would like to find all question for user, but exclude those questions who user has already endo relationship

I thought I could do :

```
MATCH (u:`User`),
  u<-[rel1:`USERS`]-(s:`Skill`),
  s-[rel2:`SKILLS`]->(k:`SkillScoring`),
  k-[rel3:`ANSWER`]->(q:`Question`),
  u<-[rel4:`ENDO`]-(e:`Endo`)

WHERE NOT((e)-->(u)) AND (u.id='1')

RETURN u, e, k, q
```

**UPDATE:**

endo nodes are connected like this.

- blue is user node
- purple is journaled endorsement node (created at)
- green is skill scoring node

In fact the relationship "ENDORSEMENT" has a node (journalised) which connects the skill scoring nodes

[image: endo relationship]

**UPDATE:**

When I execute this query, it returns me the question in connection with the user

```
MATCH (u:User),
  u<-[rel1:USERS]-(s:SoftSkill),
  s-[rel2:SOFT_SKILLS]->(k:SkillScoring),
  k-[rel3:ANSWER]->(q:Question),
  u<-[:ENDO]-()<-[:ENDO]->(k)  
WHERE u.id='1'
RETURN q, u
```

by cons when I execute this query to exclude the question, the query returns me questions but also question that I don't want

```
MATCH (u:User),
  u<-[rel1:USERS]-(s:SoftSkill),
  s-[rel2:SOFT_SKILLS]->(k:SkillScoring),
  k-[rel3:ANSWER]->(q:Question)
WHERE u.id='1' AND NOT u<-[:ENDO]-()<-[:ENDO]->(k)
RETURN q, u
```

What's wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of a question that the query fails to exclude? Perhaps a picture of your whole model where you mark a node that is returned, which shouldn't be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Your query first says that `u` has `:ENDO` relationship from `e`, then that `e` has no relationship to `u`, but that can't be.

How are endo nodes connected to scorings/questions in those cases you want to exclude? Could you try something like

```
MATCH (u:User)-[rel1:USERS]->(s:Skill)-[rel2:SKILLS]->(k:SkillScoring)-[rel3:ANSWER]->(q:Question)
WHERE u.id = '1' AND NOT u<-[:ENDO]-()-[:??]->k
```

and fill in the relationship type at `??` for how the endo node (anonymous node `()` above) is connected?

If you want you can create an example graph at http://console.neo4j.org, that would help make your intention clear.

Also, it's fine to use backticks around labels and relationships, but you don't *need* to unless they contain whitespace or some other uncommon characters.